# How many events can be present in a Javascript program

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am  new to Javascript. In fact, I am still learning the basics. I have asked this question of my peers and our mentors but I'm not getting helped. I hope it isn't because I don't know how to ask the question. Here goes.

This is where the full set of code is: https://github.com/dhawkinson/FSJSProject02

The readme file will fully explain the project. I short this is what is going on:

1. The project is a pagination and searching exercise.
2. I have a list of 64 students in the index.html file.
3. I have to list them 10 per page. with the remained on the final page.
4. I have a set of page buttons '<', '1', '2'... '7', '>'. They represent 'previous', 1 through 7 and 'next'.
5. There is a box for a name search, top right-hand corner.

The goal is to be able to do the following:

1. Display the first page.
2. Paginate using the paging buttons in any sequence I choose.
3. Key in any name or part of a name in the search box.
4. Bring up any name or names that match on either name or email.
5. Paginate (if necessary) on the name search, as with the standard paging.
6. Move between any and all of these capabilities, freely.

In terms of the functionality, I think I am in pretty good shape. I think the problem is in this snippet of code:

```
$('.page-header').append(searchHtml); //  set up the search capability (searchbox and button)
buildPagingSet();
showPage(eventType);
//  event listeners
       document.getElementById("searchVal").addEventListener("keydown",keydownListener,true);
    document.getElementById("paging").addEventListener("click",clickListener,true);
```

That is the entire bloc of, what I would call in the old days "Mainline Processing”. It is the bottom of the js file. Everything above it is either global variable declarations or functions.

I can "play scales” running up and down, back and forth on the click event. I can perform the entry and get the pattern, grab the matches dynamically and display, either a short page of results or the first page of results with the `keydown` event. But, the minute I fire the `keydown` event and get the results for the first time, both of the listeners go dead.

I have Googled every variety of “how to fire more than one event listener” that I can think of. All, I get are results showing me how to attach multiple handlers to a single event. I can find nothing that tells me how to fire more than one event that are not related to each other. I know there must be a way. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer was to put my event handlers inside of functions. I could then fire them at will and as many times as I needed.